# Count Aggregates in clingo

Tags: aggregate, answer-set-programming, clingo

Test data

```
addEmployee(EmplID, Name1, Name2, TypeOfWork, Salary, TxnDate)
addEmployee("tjb1998", "eva", "mcdowell", "ra", 55000, 20).
addEmployee("tjb1987x", "ben", "xena", "cdt", 68000, q50).
addEmployee("tjb2112", "ryoko", "hakubi", "ra", 63000, 60).
addEmployee("tjb1987", "ben", "croshaw", "cdt", 68000, 90).
addEmployee("tjb3300m", "amane", "mauna", "ma", 61000, 105).
```

I want to group by employees as per the type of work and count of employees for the particular type of work. 
e.g:

```
ra 4
cdt 2
ma 1
```

below is the query I am trying to run

```
employee(TOW) :- addEmployee(_,_,_,TOW,_,_).
nmbrEmployeesOfSameType (N) :- N = #count { employee(TOW) }.
```

Please advise, I am at the beginner level for Clingo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
addEmployee("tjb1998", "eva", "mcdowell", "ra", 55000, 20).
addEmployee("tjb1987x", "ben", "xena", "cdt", 68000, q50).
addEmployee("tjb2112", "ryoko", "hakubi", "ra", 63000, 60).
addEmployee("tjb1987", "ben", "croshaw", "cdt", 60000, 90).
addEmployee("tjb3300m", "amane", "mauna", "ma", 61000, 105).


getType(P, X) :- addEmployee(X, _, _, P, _, _).

type(P) :- addEmployee(_, _, _, P, _, _).

result(P, S) :- S = #count{ I : getType(P,I)}, type(P).

#show result/2.
```

And the output will look like:

```
clingo version 4.5.3
Reading from test.lp
Solving...
Answer: 1
result("ra",2) result("cdt",2) result("ma",1)
SATISFIABLE
```

You can also copy my code and run it [here](http://potassco.sourceforge.net/clingo.html) to see if it works.

Comment: Great! This query worked, thank you so much for your help. I was not aware if we can use getType in this. Perfect answer! Thanks again!